# Pluggin Android Development In NetBeans

Tags: android, netbeans, installation, netbeans-plugins

Im was assigned to develop a mobile application. To be honest i never develop any mobile application.

i have try add nbandroid plugin into netbeans (I'm decided to stick with netbeans because all my system development created in netbeans). When i try to add nbandroid there an error.

It's says "Unable to connect to the Android because of Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://nbandroid.org/release81/updates/updates.xml"

Can anyone help me please..

Comment: I’ll suggest you to install Android Studio. Yes you can configure Net Beans for Android development, but you’ll miss the core feature provided by Android Studio.

Comment: Ouh i see, but do you know how to set it up in netbeans?

Answer (score 2):

The author of the original NBANDROID discontinued development and canceled the nbandroid.org domain. You can compile the original NBANDROID from https://bitbucket.org/nbandroid.

Plugin development continues as the NBANDROID-V2 project for Apache NetBeans.

Instructions for installing NBANDROID-V2 can be found here:
https://github.com/NBANDROIDTEAM/NBANDROID-V2/wiki

Comment: hi i try to install but it shows  "The plugin Common Annotations is requested in version >= 1.30.1 but only 1.27.1 was found."

Comment: I tried installing that plugin on each and every apache netbeans version from 11.1 to 12.5 and it only succeeded in 11.1. so i think youll have to use 11.1. and also as of 2021,that repo has no commits since 2019